# Magento module for exporting order info

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I'm new to Magento and have some difficulties with writing mdoule that will allow me to export (send to remote API) data from my magento store.

Currently what I have is created observer for "sales_order_save_after" event and what I want do in my observer is to get Order data, make them xml and send to some remote url.

Can anyone help with that? I'm using magento 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get data in observer like below function

```
 public function orderExportTxt(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
 { 
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     print_r($order->getData()); // your user detail.
 }
```

**EDIT**

To get Product detail from order

```
<?php $order_id = 2314; //use your own order id 

    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); 
    //load order by order id 
     $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems(); 

     foreach($ordered_items as $item){     
       //item detail     
        echo $item->getItemId(); //product id     
        echo $item->getSku();     
        echo $item->getQtyOrdered(); //ordered qty of item     
        echo $item->getName();     // etc. 
   } ?>
```

its depends on your xml format for your third party service in which format it accept your order to be in saved.

below is just example to create xml file.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

hope this will sure help you.

Let me know if i could help further.